# How to implement accessibility to a custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, accessibility

I have a custom rendered control in my main window, which have some text. It doesn't support MS Active Accessibility. I have the position of the text and the text as string. How to implement it standard accessibility to it so I can make it readable for screen readers?

Comment: Most Microsoft UI frameworks have accessibility built-in. Which one are you using?

Comment: WinForms with custom control inside.

Comment: Is the custom control something you build as part of your project, or 3rd party? Is it also WinForms, or C/C++? If the custom control is your own code and is WinForms, you can use the AccessibleName and similar properties on System.Windows.Forms.Control to specify some accessibility properties.

Comment: BrendanMcK: It's third party, but open source. Also it's winforms, so I think I'll try the AccessibleName.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at implementing the [IAccessible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/accessibility.iaccessible.aspx) Interface